# Execute python script in console via bash script with double-click

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a python script, that runs fine if i run in on the console with `python3 script.py`. For some reason, the script should be executed via a bash-script "start.sh". A MWE would be

```
#!/bin/bash 
python3 GUIpyPCS.py
```

When I run the script by double-clicking it, it doesent open a terminal window. Hence, the python script is executed invisibly in the background and not on a new console window.

How can I ensure, that the python script is executed on a console by double-clicking the bash-script? Is there something I can add to the bash script? I am currently testing on Kubuntu 20.04, but the solution should also applicable to other distributions/window managers.

Comment: Call the interpreter in the first line!

Comment: @tripleee the duplicate you linked is about running a script from command line while this question is about running it from a graphical file manager. The questions are different and the answers are as well. IMHO, it's not a dupe.

Comment: @Friedrich Thanks for the feedback; I added a second duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**---------- Assumptions ----------**

- the script is in a directory
- you open that directory in the graphics interface (Nemo, Nautilus, any other file manager)
- you double-click the icon representing the script
- you expect to see a terminal window open, with the script execution in it

**---------- In your script do ----------**

- start a terminal window
- that terminal command includes a call to the script
- and lastly a call to the `read` command, to keep the window opened until you are done
- you press enter to close the window

**---------- Ex ----------**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
xterm -e "/bin/ls /etc; read" &
```

**---------- Details ----------**

- the `-e` option to `xterm` is the command that will be executed in the new window
- I put `/bin/ls /etc; read` instead of your script.  You would put `your_script.bash arg1 arg2; read`
- you could do something similar with `gnome-terminal` instead of `xterm`
- the `read` is not essential, it could be a `sleep 5` for example.  Or if your script already has a delay or something,  you might not need anything.
- I used `xterm` since it is available on all distributions, which ever window manager you use.

Answer (score -2):

**1)** Create 0.sh file in **(project folder)** with your script. Then edit It under text editor  and put to It:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 
pyton3 0.py
```

Save the 0.sh file.

**2)** Right Click on 0.sh file.

**3)** Permissions Tab / Set As Runnable.

**4)** Righi Click on 0.sh file / Open with other Application / Use as Custom Command:

type: `bash`

set mark: Use as Default...

press: ok ...

**5)** 0.sh file must be in the Project Folder.

**6)** Double Click on 0.sh file.

Comment: This seems to weirdly assume some particular GUI (Windows?)

Comment: What is the problem? It's under linux and solve problem, or not?

Comment: If these are instructions for a particular desktop environment (Gnome? Ubuntu? KDE? LXDE?) you need to spell that out. Separately, item #5 seems like bogus, or perhaps I don't understand what it is trying to say.

Comment: OP asked about Kubuntu 20.04 and applicability to other configurations. I don't have access to KDE right now so I really can't say if it applies.

Comment: I'm using linux system! Brow! And there is used linux hashtag in question too.

Comment: The problem is that there is not the one Linux desktop manager but there are many of them. tripleee enumerated some. Your instructions are for one specific manager and might not work for another. It will help future readers if you're explicit about for which one your answer is. As I said, I would assume KDE but I can't confirm right now.